# Using WHERE or ON to filter

Tags: mysql, sql

Example A

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.key = table2.key
WHERE table2.key IS NULL;
```

Example B

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.key = table2.key AND table2.key IS NULL;
```

Would the two SQL queries above be logically equivalent or what is the point of filtering within the `ON`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example1** - `WHERE` clause condition filters the final result so your example1 returns data from `table1` for which matching data is not present in `table2` as `left join` is based on `key` and after that `where` condition filters all the records that have no matching `key` in the `table2` - **you will find less than or equal to total `table1` record in the result**

**Example2** - Condition in the `ON` is used to join two tables so your example2 will give you all the data from `table1` and only matching data from `table2`. But as you have used conflicting condition in the `ON` clause (`ON table1.key = table2.key AND table2.key IS NULL`), your example2 will return all data for `table1` and no data for `table2`(`null` in all columns for table2) - **final result will have number of records equal to number of records in `table1`.**

Answer (score 1):

**Example B** will JOIN nothing because ON clause will be always FALSE.

So technically your **Example B** is equal to:

```
SELECT my_column
FROM table1
```

When **Example A** will return all records from table A which have no matching records in table B.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jtCfu3ti1Rd3VDUB69iquF/0